My object not fully transparent and fade out problem

Edited because a similar but not identical issue existed in the forum.

"Mix Shader" and "Transparent BSDF" have been added to the object in the scene. There is a copy of this object with the same X and Y coordinates. that is, two objects on top of each other. The shader nodes of both objects are the same. However, when I render, the object is not completely transparent.


My next step after this problem is that I do not want the inside of the object to be visible while fading out. Is this possible?


Consider uploading your blend file with packed textures : https://blend-exchange.com/. Hard to answer without more informations, I'm guessing the overlapping objects are involved.

By the way, a Principled BSDF shader node has an Alpha channel. Mixing the node with a white Transparent BSDF is like reducing the Alpha value in the Principled BSDF so your material setup is a bit redundant. And when there are two identical objects on top of each other I guess there might be overlapping geometry and therefore Z fighting?

In the Render Settings > Light Paths make sure you crank up the Transparent bounces. By default it is something like 8 and anything higher than that will result in black faces


Here is my project file. When I set the Settings>Light pats value to 25, this problem almost disappeared. But I don't know if it's better to do this.

@ugr's The Settings > Light Paths value? Which one, all of them? As Gorgious said, when you have many transparent objects in the scene, the default Transparent value of 8 is not sufficient. And yes, it is better to do this. Actually, with lot of transparent objects it is the only way you can get rid of these black artifacts. Keeping a low Transparent bounces value cannot be compensated elsewhere. I would set the value to at least 32 or even 64 (I have mine at 128 per default but you don't have to go so high),

Does this answer your question? Black artifacts when looking through many transparent objects? (Note that the accepted answer there is misleading, it is not the Transmission bounces, but the Transparent bounces as described in my other answer there.)

I looked at the page you sent. I think it sounds like my situation. As @Gorgios and you mentioned, I set the Light Pats value to 32 and my problem was solved. My next step after this problem is that I do not want the inside of the object to be visible while fading out. Is this possible?
